# using array.map to use key of object array of array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

is there anyway I can use `array.map` to apply a function that parameter is key of array.object in typescript?
I have one object array inside of array. the object with key min and max. I would like to do something like someArrayFunction(array.map(func1(key), array.map())) so I can compare the value from each key of object array

```
const allVariables: any[] =  [
  [ { name: 'a', value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: {min: 1, max: 2}}, { name: 'b', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: {min:11, max: 22} }],
  [ { name: 'a1',value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: {min: 1, max: 2}}, {name: 'b1', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: {min:11, max: 22} }],
  [ { name: 'a2',value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: {min: 1, max: 2}}, {name: 'b2', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: {min:11, max: 22} }],
  ];

allVariables.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    // someArrayFunction(someFunc(obj.name, key), obj.value[key])
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name a
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name b
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name a1
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name b1
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name c1
    // so to compare value.min === expect.min from name c1

  })
})

// someArrayFunction(parameter: string[], v: number){
  // do something with parameter and v...
// }
```

Comment: what result do you want to receive?

Comment: I want to have something `someArrayFunction([min, max], [expect.min, expect.max])`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if you wanted that.

```
const allVariables: any[] =  [
  [
    { name: 'a', value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: { min: 1, max: 2 } },
    { name: 'b', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: { min:11, max: 22 } },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'a1',value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: { min: 1, max: 2 } },
    { name: 'b1', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: { min:11, max: 22} },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'a2',value:{min: 1, max: 2}, expect: { min: 1, max: 2 } },
    { name: 'b2', value: {min: 11, max: 22}, expect: { min:11, max: 22 } },
  ],
];

allVariables.forEach(array => {
  array.forEach(obj => {
    const {value, expect} = obj;

    console.log(someArrayFunction(obj, value));
  })
})


function someArrayFunction(value, expect) {
  return value.min === expect.min;
}
```